# error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git

Данная ошибка возникает, когда происходит следующее:

- я создал проект в idea
- залил его на github
- нужно было добавить изменения в проект
- произвел изменения
- хочу добавить изменения в через git (вот тут данная ошибка и появляется)

Я просто не понимаю как именно действовать в таких ситуациях, потому что иногда ошибка есть, иногда нет, иногда получается ее исправить, иногда нет.

[image: скриншот из idea]

Comment: Ну видимо ты либо напрямую в гитхабе что-то правил и оно не совпадает с твоей локальной версией, либо кто-то ещё...

Comment: а как пофиксить? и как правильно делать изменения? Это мой локальный проект, только я могу менять там что-то

Comment: Ну не надо делать ненужных манипуляцй напрямую в гитхабе - всякие удаления например. Коммит по изменению ещё ок. А ты наверняка там что-то удалил........ вот не надо так.....а лучше вообще всегда работать только через гит на пк, раз уж ты его поставил

Comment: так к том и дело, в github я ничего не изменяю, только через git

Comment: Есть ветка а, выкачали изменения, начали править, вы же позже на другом пк(или копии репозитория) в ветку а делаете коммит и возвращаетесь на первый пк и там делаете коммит. Вот тут и будет ошибка. Если вы заливали что то в репозиторий, то перед отправкой, сначала надо выкачать изменения из ветки. А вообще, лучше работать в отдельных ветках и позже их сливать

Comment: А что это у Вас на фотке? Это git bash?

Comment: не знаю почему удалили ваш комментарий, но команда  git push -f origin main помогла, а остальное нет. Просто я делаю изменения только на рабочем пк, проект на github пустой

Comment: @EgorBelogolovtcev ок. Восстановлю ответ. Просто я его написал, прочитав Вашу фотку очень быстро и невнимательно. Потом перечитал, и понял, что хотел бы написать по-другому. 
А еще была мысль, что Ваша локальная ветка не является отслеживающей удаленную (опция `--track`).
Переписывать совсем не хотелось. Вот и удалил :)

Answer (score 1):

Тит просил Вас сделать `pull`. Но, судя по фотке, `pull` не удался. Потом Вы пробовали что-то коммитить, но коммитить было нечего.

В общем пробуйте следующее:

1. открываем git bash (консоль гита). Если не устанавливали консоль отдельно, я бы рекомендовал установить, даже если консоль можно открыть через ж..., то есть через клиенты вроде SourceTree или прочие.
2. Переходим в репозиторий

   ```
   cd путь_к_репозиторию
   ```
3. проверьте, установлена ли ссылка на удаленный репозиторий. Судя по Вашему рассказу, она должна там быть. Но судя по фотке вроде команда `pull` какая-то странная. В консоли она бы выглядела так

   ```
   git pull origin main
   ```

   `origin` - это имя ссылки на удаленный репозиторий. Имя `origin` общепринятое, хотя у Вас может быть и другое имя.

   Проверить ссылку можно командой

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```
4. Если ссылка не установлена, устанавливаем

   ```
   git remote add origin ссылка_на_удаленный_репозиторий
   ```
5. Выполняем pull по-нормальному

   ```
   git pull origin main
   ```
6. Вносим изменения в репозиторий, коммитим

   ```
   git add .
   ```

   или

   ```
   git add имя_нужного_файла
   ```
7. Заливаем в удаленный репо изменения

   ```
   git push origin main
   ```

**Если это все не помогло** просто залейте изменения с опцией `--force` или флагом `-f` (это тоже самое)

```
    git push -f origin main
```

Это точно прокатит, но применять это нужно осторожно. Если в Вашу ветку кто-то уже успел накоммитить, то Вы можете затереть чужие коммиты

Как-то так...

Comment: Спасибо, помогла команда git push -f origin main